# React PropTypes.oneOf to specify an enum doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a problem to specify a property of type 'enum' in react. According to the documentation here [React multiple components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) the following snippet should work :

```
position : React.PropTypes.oneOf(['rightTop','rightBottom'])
```

But I get the following error

```
ERROR in ./app/components/mqttComponents/mqttPresence.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError:/Users/giuseppe/Projects/sw-director/app/components/mqttComponents/mqttPresence.jsx: Unexpected token (68:36)
66 |   propTypes : {
67 |     //position: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
> 68 |     position : React.PropTypes.oneOf(['rightTop','rightBottom']),
                                           ^
 69 |     showMqttClientStatus : React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
 70 |     mqtt: React.PropTypes.object
 71 |   }
```

I don't realise which is the error? Maybe is something related to the new ES6 syntax ?

Comment: Since this is a syntax error, this doesn't have anything to do with `oneOf` specifically.

Comment: @FelixKling I know, therefore there is a mismatch between the documentation of the `oneOf` and its implementation.According to the documentation is a function that takes an array as argument whilst it's not. So what is it ?

Comment: Again, its a **syntax** error, not a *runtime* error. The issue is not with the `oneOf` function or the value you pass in. The issue is with the characters you typed in the file (simplified). But why would get an error there, I don't know.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

With the ES6 syntax the propTypes in React should be defined as a static property. So the only difference should be in the propTypes declaration.

```
static propTypes = {
     position : React.PropTypes.oneOf(['rightTop','rightBottom']),
     showMqttClientStatus : React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
```

Comment: It completely works!! I knew it was something related to ES6 but I couldn't fix it... Thanks